# How to add line number for the last line of abstract?

Tags: abstract, line-numbering

I'm writing a paper and line numbers are needed. I've used the `\usepackage{lineno}`, and add `\begin{linenomath*}\end{linenomath*}`around abstract. However, there is no line number on the last line of abstract. How to deal with it? Thank you!

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. But my reputation is not enough, I cannot attach the picture to illustrate my question.

Comment: @OldPanda: You can include a link to the picture. Those with edit privileges will correct this and embed the image. We're also interested in a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) which should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. It will make things easier for both you and the community trying to help you.

Comment: Without a MWE, this is 'unclear' I'm afraid.